# Cannot run blackberry simulator 9800

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i just downaloded the hello world source code from the blackberry site and able to run it succesfully using eclipse.

> But when i run the same application
>   today , the simulator shows as "JVM
>   Error 563" "FS Multiple Errors" Scroll
>   for available commands "Reset .

i even cleaned the build and restarted my system also,  but the error is not fixed.

how can i fix this problem

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Window -> show view -> Service Manager (if not see in other)

[image]

**Edit:**

Recently I see that Reset != clean up.

To clean simulator, you need to run `clean.bat` file.
Refer to my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677597/could-not-load-blackberry-webworkphonegap-application-in-blackberry-6-0-simulato/6703039#6703039).

Comment: Hi Vikas, can you pls tell me where i can find the service manager in the eclipse