# Could not load BlackBerry webwork+PhoneGap application in BlackBerry 6.0 simulator

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-webworks

I have my application ready on BlackBerry webwork and PhoneGap.
I successfully run it using eclipse plug-in for BB 5.0 and BB 6.0.

But when I tried to wipe user data from BB 6.0 and tried to directly load `.cod` file from `StandardInstall` directory, application does not open. It just display splash screen.
I get error like

> "ApplicationRegistry.wait For (0x3bc6259193b4b87c) timeout"

I am wondering that is it a simulator bug or something?

Notes:

1. I tested both singed and unsigned application.
2. Above mentioned method works on any simulator for BB 5.0
3. I also created normal BlackBerry application (without phoneGap and webwork) and I was able to load `.cod` file in BB 6.0.
4. I'd also like to present my question regarding difference between OTAInstall and StandardInstall. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676656/difference-between-otainstall-and-standardinstall-in-blackberry).
5. Simulator information: Torch 9800 (6.0.0.227)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a simulator cleaning up issue.

I was using `Reset` option to clean simulator. But this will not work.

You need to run `clean.bat` file from simpack directory.

My path was:

> D:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.browser.tools.wcpc_2.0.0.201103231828-18\wcpc\simpack\6.0.0.227

Answer (score 0):

Use a Blackberry specific phonegap.js file. This will clear all the popup related issues.